# bash true/false redirection error

Tags: bash, testing

On `bash 4.2.8(1)-release` (`x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`) on Ubuntu 11.04 this command

```
[ $(wc -l /var/www/some.log|cut -d " " -f 1) -le 6 ] || echo "no"
```

yields

```
 echo: command not found
```

for as long as the `||` clause would come into affect. The `&&` clause is working. I have tried changing the order (`||` first, `&&` first) to no avail.

Funny things is,

```
true && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

yields

```
yes
```

and

```
false && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

yields

```
no
```

so I suppose something is wrong with my test-clause. I'd like to check if the file length of some.log is less or equal to 6, if not then do something else then if yes.

Double brackets in the test-clause don't not work, either.

The long-form of test does work, though:

```
test $(wc -l /var/www/some.log|cut -d " " -f 1) -le 6 && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

Funny, huh?

As always, thank you for any tips/hints on this.

```
Christian.
```

Comment: Does it work if you use /bin/echo instead?  If so, try /usr/bin/env to check your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with 2 [ and ]):

```
[[ $(wc -l /var/www/some.log|cut -d " " -f 1) -le 6 ]] || echo "no"
^^                                                  ^^
```

From the bash's man:

> **Compound Commands**
>
> ...
>
> `[[ expression ]]`
>
> Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on  the  evaluation  of the conditional  expression expression.  Expressions are composed of the primaries described  below  under  CONDITIONAL  EXPRESSIONS.

I guess the single [ and ] is not a standard was of performing tests, even if it works on my side.

**Edit:**

Actually, [ and ] are a standard way of doing tests, it is a buildin command in bash.  If [[ ... ]] works and [ ... ] is not working, I would not fully understand it.  It might have something to do with expansion performed/not performed in [ and ].

Comment: disregarding my typo in that line: "Double brackets in the test-clause don't not work, either." so somehow, no, that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17648585/612462) - your space is `0xC2 0xA0` instead of `0x20`. Copy-pasted and stripped from your question:

```
$ echo "  echo " | hexdump -C
00000000  20 c2 a0 65 63 68 6f 20  0a                       | ..echo .|
00000009
#            ^^ ^^                                            ^^
```

After deleting and re-typing the two leading spaces:

```
$ echo "  echo " | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 65 63 68 6f 20 0a                           |  echo .|
00000008
#            ^^                                               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why yours isn't working

Try this

```
 :>bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.


[ $( wc -l < /var/www/some.log  ) -le 6 ] || echo no
no
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.