# bash: wrong behavior in for... loop together with a test statement

Tags: bash, testing, echo

I am trying to test if certain files, called up in a list of textfiles, are in a certain directory. Every once in a while (and I am quite certain I use the same statements every time) I get an error, complaining that the `echo` command cannot be found.

The textfiles I have in my directory `/audio/playlists/` are named according to their date on which they are supposed to be used: `20130715.txt` for example for today:

```
me@computer:/some/dir# ls /audio/playlists/
20130715.txt  20130802.txt  20130820.txt  20130907.txt  20130925.txt
20130716.txt  20130803.txt  20130821.txt  20130908.txt  20130926.txt
(...)

me@computer:/some/dir# cat /audio/playlists/20130715.txt
#A Comment line goes here
00:00:00 141-751.mp3
00:03:35 141-704.mp3
00:06:42 140-417.mp3
00:10:46 139-808.mp3
00:15:13 136-126.mp3
00:20:26 071-007.mp3
(...)
23:42:22 136-088.mp3
23:46:15 128-466.mp3
23:50:15 129-592.mp3
23:54:29 129-397.mp3
```

So much for the facts. The following statement, which lets me `test` if all files called upon in all of the textfiles in the given directory are actually a file in the directory `/audio/mp3/`, produces an error:

```
me@computer:/some/dir# for i in $(cat /audio/playlists/*.txt|cut -c 10-16|sort|uniq); do [ -f "/audio/mp3s/$i.mp3" ] || echo $i; done
 echo: command not found
me@computer:/some/dir#
```

I would *guess* `bash` wants to complain about the "A Comment"-line (actually `" line "`) not being a file, but why would that cause `echo` not to be found? Again, *mostly* this works, but every so often I get this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try replacing `echo` with `/bin/echo`

Comment: Check the output of `file /audio/playlists/20130715.txt`; I suspect DOS line endings. Try quoting (`echo "$i"`) as well.

Comment: Did the below answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That space before `echo` isn't U+0020, it's U+00A0. And indeed, the command `" echo"` doesn't exist.

Comment: eh, then how'd you figure it out?